# Patent software workflow (yet to have implementation)

Tags: software, utility-patent

I'm unsure if this question is same to my previous question, [Idea for Software - Should I file Patent first](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/idea-for-software-should-i-file-patent-first)

I have idea for Utility pattern. Already I create the output (2 to 3 hours in MS Word). And I envision how the software will greet the user, ask for inputs, user presses `Submit` and the output is produced.

Does my patent have to describe the software implementation (the programming language, line-by-line code), or just a workflow of how to the software works (with pictures and drawings as in [this example](https://keynotopia.com/guides-ppt/))

I believe the answer is `YES` but I request your clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a patent application does not need to be detailed to the level of source code. Most patents involving software do have multiple sheets of flowcharts. The specification usually talks about each box in each flowchart and walks the reader through the process step by step.

You can use [google patents](https://patents.google.com/) with some keywords to bring up examples of patents involving software. This is an example of an [Amazon patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7877299B2/) with very little detail pictured and a [VISA patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9953378B2/) with many pages of system diagrams and flowcharts.

Comment: Thank you for these links @george-white